# can we change Description in zend framework in client side with jquery or javascripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zend-framework

i have created a form with zend framework and this form have some elements that all elements have a description , i set description with setDescription in design time, i want to know can 
i change this Description in client side with jquery or javascripts?

Comment: @ulduz114: can you rework your question, I don't really understand and I think I am not alone in this case ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the Zend Fremework [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.elements.html)

> Description: appends the element
>   description. If none is present,
>   nothing is appended. By default, the
>   description is rendered in a
>
> tag
>   with a class of 'description'.

so you can use jquery to change the content of that p tag

i.e. (not verified)

```
$('#your_form_id_element + p.description').html('foobar');
```

PS: you probably want to check what markup `ZF` output and change the selector I have made